# Mongodb | Check if any other key exist in object field other than given key in object field | length of object field type

Tags: mongodb, object, mongodb-query

We have one use case. Let's suppose I have two documents as given below.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID('123'),
  "test": {
     "a":1,
      "b":1
   }
},
{
  "_id": ObjectID('456'),
  "test": {
     "a":1
   }
```

Now I want those result whose "test" field has property other than "a" or in another way, I want those objects which have multiple keys/properties in a "test" field or to check the size of an object greater than 1

So, the result will be:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectID('123'),
   "test": {
      "a":1,
       "b":1
    }
}
```

I tried to make a query for the above output as shown below and it working as expected

`db.col.find({"test": {"$gt": {"a": 1} }})`

So, is that the right thing to do? Any downside of doing it? We want to lever-age indexes as well

Please let me know your inputs on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bluMAU_0Dre

Use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) `{ "$objectToArray": "$test" }` convert to array

get the size [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) os array

[$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) check if it's more than 1

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [ { $size: { "$objectToArray": "$test" } }, 1 ]
  }
})
```

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

> Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the right way to do this? is there any downside to do this? we want to  leaver-age indexes as well

Comment: @beginner `db.col.find({"test": {"$gt": {"a": 1} }})` query can use index `db.collection.createIndex({ test: 1 })` which will be faster.